# Codeigniter form validation is doing TRUE and FALSE actions (weird bug!)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a weird bug.

Form validation is doing both TRUE and FALSE actions.

For TRUE, the database model (scrape_url_model) runs so the database is updated, but then the views are run as though form validation is FALSE.
The FALSE view (scrape_url/index) is shown instead of the view associated with a successful validation (scrape_url/form_success).

I'm getting the validation error message `The URL is already in the database` from the callback function.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');

    $data['pageTitle'] = 'URL Scraping Tool';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_url', 'URL', 'trim|required|callback_url_check');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);  
            $this->load->view('scrape_url/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else {
        $this->load->library('Db_queries');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        list($session_data['alert'],
        $session_data['alert_type'],
        $session_data['countUncategorizedDecks'],
        $session_data['event_id'],
        $session_data['eventDate']) = $this->scrape_url_model->insert_decks_and_cards();

        if ($this->input->post('last_url') == 'yes'){
            $this->scrape_url_model->insert_md_percentage($session_data['eventDate']);
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);  
        $this->load->view('scrape_url/form_success', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer_ajax');    
    }
}                      

public function url_check($event_url) {
    $url_regex = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";

    if (preg_match($url_regex, $event_url) == FALSE) {
        // check to see if input is a URL
        $this->form_validation->set_message('url_check', 'Please enter a URL including "http://".');
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT url FROM event';
    $s = $this->db->conn_id->query($sql);
    $used_urls = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);               

    if (in_array($event_url, $used_urls)){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('url_check', 'The URL is already in the database.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using statement:

```
$this->form_validation->run() == true
```

and then code your conditions accordingly. It will work and will also easy to understand.